# How to loop through an array and display user input with indexes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

How do i loop through an array and display user input with indexes without the user input replicating?

Current output i'm getting:

Feedback 1

123456

Feedback 2

123456

The expected output for the case below should be:

Feedback 1

123

Feedback 2

456

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    </head>

    <body> 
    
    <h2>Feedback Form</h2><br>

    <form>
        Enter Feedback : <textarea rows="3" cols="20" id="feedback"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit Feedback" id="create" onclick="addFeedback()"><br><br>
        <input type="button" value="View Feedback" id="view" onclick="displayFeedback()"><br><br>
    </form>

    <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
var myArray = [];

var myFeedback = document.getElementById("feedback");
var displayBox = document.getElementById("result");

function addFeedback(){
    

    //Store feedback into array
    myArray.push(myFeedback.value);

    //Clear textbox
    myFeedback.value = "";

    //Display message
    displayBox.innerHTML = "Successfully Added Feedback Details!";

    }   
   
   function displayFeedback(){
    
    displayBox.innerHTML = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    displayBox.innerHTML += "Feedback " + (i+1) + "<br/>" + myArray.join();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `myArray[i]` instead of `join`. Or more modern approach:

```js
let innerHTML = "<ul>";

myArray.forEach((value, index) => {
    innerHTML += `<li>Feedback ${index+1}: <br /> ${value}</li>`; 
});

innerHTML += "</ul>";

displayBox.innerHTML = innerHTML;
```